How to get total allocated size in custom operator delete[]?
I understand we can use Class-specific overloads of operator new[]/delete[] to specify our own memory allocation strategy.
So I write the following code. I barely want to use the held field to record how much memory of a type X<id> is allocated on heap.
However, I meet the problem that in operator new[], I can get the count, while I can't in operator delete[]. So in operator delete[], I don't know how much memory is actually released.
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <int Id>
struct X {
    static inline int held = 0;
    static void* operator new(std::size_t count)
    {
        held += count;
        return ::operator new(count);
    }
 
    static void* operator new[](std::size_t count)
    {
        held += count;
        return ::operator new[](count);
    }

    static void operator delete(void* ptr)
    {
        held -= sizeof(X<Id>);
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }

    static void operator delete[] (void* ptr)
    {
        // This is not correct.
        // However, I don't know the count.
        held -= sizeof(X<Id>);
        ::operator delete [] (ptr);
    }

    std::string s1;
    std::vector<int> v1;
};

int main() {
    auto * dx2 = new X<1>[100]();
    printf("x1d2 %d\n", X<1>::held);
    delete [] dx2;
    printf("x1d2 released %d\n", X<1>::held); // exptected 0
}

I understand one way is that I can allocate an extra bytes to store the count, it introduces extra overhead though.
Moreover, the compiler will actually store the count somewhere when compiling operator delete [], however, it is not exposed to users. I think I am now allowed to access the count.

Before C++14 that can be done only by having some,kind of global observer system (which probably would be there anyway, if we are up to customizing allocation

Since C++14, there are flavors of operator delete (number (5)) and operator delete[] (number (6)), that you can override and have an additional parameter for the allocated size:

void operator delete  ( void* ptr, std::size_t sz ) noexcept;   (5)
void operator delete[]  ( void* ptr, std::size_t sz ) noexcept; (6)

These operators have priority over the ones without the size (at least for classes with non-trivial destructor like yours):

Called instead of (1,2) if a user-defined replacement is provided,
except that it's unspecified whether (1,2) or (5,6) is called when
deleting objects of incomplete type and arrays of non-class and
trivially-destructible class types.

In your case you can replace your operator delete and operator delete[] with:
static void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
    held -= sz;
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}

static void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
    held -= sz;
    ::operator delete[](ptr);
}

Output on MSVC (last value is 0 as expected):
x1d2 7208
x1d2 released 0

Live demo
Some notes:

held should better be a size_t to match the type in the new and delete operators.
My live demo is using std::cout instead of the less-recommnded C style printfs.
In the live demo held has different values after the allocation in different compilers because the size of classes is implementation dependant (but it is always 0 after deallocation).
Regarding classes with a trivial destructor (which is not your case, and mentioned just for completess):

Using this variant of operator delete[] may cause memory increase for classes with a trivial destructor, because it will force the compiler to store the size (that otherwise it would not have to).
If defined at global scope (not your case), the sized variant is not guaranteed to be called (it is only guaranteed to be called for classes with non-trivial destructors).



